# Getting all friends in DNN programmatically

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I am trying to retrieve all the `friends` of a particular user. From the DNN `RelationshipController` I can only find the way to get the relationship between two users. Is it possible to get all the friends of a user?

'Get the relationship between two users:

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.Social.RelationshipController.Instance.GetFriendRelationship(Me.UserInfo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this code lying around.  I get the current user, then get all relationships userIds that are friends (vs. follower) and are 'Accepted'.  Using that list, I join back to the Users list to get the friend's user attributes and return as a new object.

Hope this helps.

```
private const int DNNSOCIAL_RELATIONSHIPTYPE_FRIEND = 1;
private const int DNNSOCIAL_RELATIONSHIPTYPE_FOLLOWER = 2;

public List<UserFriend> GetUserFriends(int portalid, int userid)
{
    UserInfo currentUser = UserController.GetUserById(portalid, userid);

    var friends = currentUser.Social.UserRelationships
                    .Where(r => r.RelationshipId == DNNSOCIAL_RELATIONSHIPTYPE_FRIEND 
                        && r.Status == RelationshipStatus.Accepted);

    return (from f in friends
            join u in UserController.GetUsers(portalid).Cast<UserInfo>()
            on f.RelatedUserId equals u.UserID
            select new UserFriend { UserId = u.UserID,  DisplayName = u.DisplayName, ProfilePicUrl = u.Profile.PhotoURL }).ToList();
}
```

...

```
public class UserFriend
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**VB.NET version**

```
Public Function GetUserFriends(portalid As Integer, userid As Integer) As List(Of UserFriend)
    Dim currentUser As UserInfo = UserController.GetUserById(portalid, userid)

Dim friends = currentUser.Social.UserRelationships.Where(Function(r) r.RelationshipId = DNNSOCIAL_RELATIONSHIPTYPE_FRIEND AndAlso r.Status = Social.RelationshipStatus.Accepted)

Return (From f In friends
        Join u In UserController.GetUsers(portalid).Cast(Of UserInfo)()
        On f.RelatedUserId Equals u.UserID
        Select New UserFriend With {.UserId = u.UserID, .DisplayName = u.DisplayName, .ProfilePicUrl = u.Profile.PhotoURL}).ToList()
 End Function
```

Comment: I have just noticed that it works only one the one end of the users. The user who sends the request and friendship is established can view the when calling the above function. However, the receiver sees himself as a friend when calling this function from his profile. Any ideas?